# Controlled database insert

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have created a script that uses PDO database functions to pull in data from an external feed and insert it into a database, which some days could amount to hundreds of entries.. the page hangs until it's done and there is no real control over it, if there is an error I don't know about it until the page has loaded.

Is there a way to have a controlled insert, so that it will insert X amount, then pause a few seconds and then continue on until it is complete?

During its insert it also executes other queries so it can get quite heavy.

I'm not quite sure what I am looking so have struggled to find help on Google.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use background tasks for that. Pausing your PHP script will not help you in speeding up page loading. Apache (or nginx or any other web-server) sends whole HTTP packet back to browser only when PHP script is completed.

You can use some functions related to output stream and if web-server supports chunked transfer then you can see progress while your page is loading. But for this purpose many developers use AJAX-queries. One query for one chunk of data. And store position of chunk in a session.

But as I wrote at first the better way would be using background tasks and workers. There are many ways of implementation this approach. You can use some specialized services like RabbitMQ, Gearman or something like that. And you can just write your own console application that you will start and check by cron-task.